# Average weight of fuel required to carry 1Kg additional cargo weight per hour

Tags: fuel, cargo, weight, fuel-consumption

I'm looking for an average number here, I know there is not one correct answer as there are many parameters to take into account.
Alternatively, I could also use something different, like : how many extra fuel does it take to carry 1kg extra freight from city A to city B.
I guess there is more chance to find empirical data than a perfect answer.

I've found many articles explaining that airlines can save XX€ by removing YY item from the plane, or that it's worth replacing crew books by ipad etc...
And it makes total sense that less weight = less fuel required.

But I've not found any details that would allow me to calculate what I need.

Basically, I want to be able to estimate if it's worth replacing an item by a ligther but more expensive one in an aircraft.

The only thing I found so far is this :
Weight of fuel required to carry 1Kg additional weight per hour : 0,04  Kg

But I've no idea where it comes from, so I'd appreciate if you could confirm and give some detail.

Ultimately, my goal is to get airlines to switch to ligther stuff so they emit less CO2.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Related: [How much does it cost extra to fly with one additional passenger?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/67382/how-much-does-it-cost-extra-to-fly-with-one-additional-passenger)

Comment: To give more context, my company manufactures cargo pallet nets.  So ideally I'd like to get an average figure that would work for a B747 400 full freigther fully loaded. My goal being to calculate how much fuel can be saved by replacing the 39 PMC nets by ligther products and see how much can be saved over a year of operation.

Comment: OK, so if I understood well the other post, a good average is 0.005 gallon per extra pound, so about 0.042 liter per extra kilogram, this is quite big! It means about 60 USD saving per year each time you remove 1kg of weight

Comment: I answered a similar question on Physics.SE: [Does it take significantly more fuel to fly a heavier airplane?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/133893/52188)