# How does fuel economy on Diamond DA62 change as passenger weight increases?

Tags: aircraft-performance, fuel-consumption

How many more gallons per hour is required to fly extra 1kg of weight on a Diamond DA62 aircraft or similar aircraft?

Comment: Have you looked for the Pilot Information Manual (PIM) for the plane?

Comment: You'd need the fuel consumption and cruise performance charts for the plane and extrapolate the number from the speed penalty you incur from an increase in weight from x to y. Normal cruise power is 75% of maximum. You might find that at a 75% power setting at a minimum weight, each extra kg costs you some fraction of a knot in cruise speed. Work out the increased power required to maintain that speed, and the fuel burn from that power increase, and there you are.

Comment: Related for jet aircraft: [How much does it cost extra to fly with one additional passenger?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/67382/how-much-does-it-cost-extra-to-fly-with-one-additional-passenger)