# Landing at 30,000 ft

Tags: aircraft-performance, landing, pilot-technique

Excluding how a runway would exist at 30,000 ft, could landing a plane at that altitude be done? What would it take to do so?

[image]
Very Basic Wind rose for Mount Everest

Weather Phenomena That Could Impact Aviation Operations:

High Density altitude (1/3) density altitude of sea level. Planes capable of a ceiling of 35000 ft required. Ground effect deceleration landing required.  Strong crosswinds and updrafts present year-round. Build from ice, the runway is 3 to 5 times longer to compensate for Density Altitude, wind, and ice. 10 percent chance of rain year-round. In the middle of June to September the monsoon season produces heavy precipitation. The temperature ranges from -2º F to -76º F. Banner clouds often present. The Subtropical jet stream maybe present with winds exceeding 80mph. If the Polar jet stream merges with the sub-tropical jet stream wind could exceeded 120mph. Supplemental oxygen maybe needed. Presume landing is done in head-wind only.

Comment: Landing is less of a problem. All it needs is a very long runway, tires strong enough for the higher speeds and a beefed-up landing gear for the higher sink speed. Taking off again from this runway will be the really hard part!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What would be the challenges to taking off and landing a typical passenger jet at FL300?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/67999/what-would-be-the-challenges-to-taking-off-and-landing-a-typical-passenger-jet-a)

Comment: @PeterKämpf what about flap speed?

Comment: @Abdullah The flap speed limits are IAS limits and you would land at the same IAS. It's just that this IAS would correspond to a much higher TAS at these altitudes.